# Какую роль играет Модуль в Angular2

Tags: angular2

Хочется глубже понять суть Angular2. Поэтому вопрос к тем, кто хорошо разобрался.

1. Зачем разделены модули и компоненты? Почему нельзя было прописать все
   imports, providers и declarations в компоненте?
2. При вызове компонента в качестве замены тега сначала подгружается компонент, затем модуль. При вызове из route-module сначала грузим модуль, затем компонент. Как правильно?
3. Можно ли в одном файле объединить модуль и компонент, если компоненты небольшие?

Информации на эту тему много, но вся она противоречивая. Хотелось бы коротко и по-русски: Как лучше выстраивать структуру?

==========
В комментариях обсудить не получается, буду уточнять здесь.
to Dimanoid

1. Вот именно это "разные компоненты одного модуля" и интересует.
   У меня пока получается один компонент-один модуль. (точнее, на компонент приходится блок из 4 файлов: модуль, компонент, html и css). Иначе не получается. Если, к примеру для компонента надо обязательно загрузить MaterialModule. Без модуля компонент не проходит, попытки загрузить один раз на более верхнем уровне - тоже. Или я что-то не так делаю. Отсюда и возникает вопрос о правильной структуре.
2. Компоненты я вызываю в двух случаях:
   -- при роутинге. В этом случае сначала приходится импортировать модуль в routing-module старшего уровня, затем в модуле декларировать компонент
   -- при создании своего тега (селектора). В этом случае в компоненте верхнего уровня декларирую компонент, а в нем уже импортирую модуль.
   Опять же, вовсе не уверен в правильности своих действий. Дошел методом тыка.
3. Бывает, что и компонент маленький и подгрузить надо один-два внешних модуля. Напрашивается желание сделать 1-2 файла вместо 4-х. Тем более, встречал такое в примерах.Но стоит ли так делать

to  Mr. Brightside

Структура такая:
ComponentLevel0

--ComponentLevel1

----ComponentLevel2

------ComponentLevel3

--------ComponentLevel4

Level1 вызывается из Level0 посредством роутинга через route-module

Шаблон Level1 содержит тег селектора Level2

Шаблон Level2 содержит тег селектора Level3

Шаблон Level3 содержит тег селектора Level4

Все уровни используют MaterialModule и FormsModule
Пока пришел к следующему (поначалу так не работало, но сейчас получилось):

Level0 в Level0.routing-module импортирует Level1.module и MaterialModule

Level1.module декларирует Level1.component

Он же декларирует компоненты Level2.component, Level3.component, Level4.component

Он же импортирует MaterialModule и FormsModule

Пока так работает.
А вот попытка отказаться от MaterialModule в Level1.module (казалось бы, уже импортирован в Level0.module) успехом не увенчалась.
Чего-то я еще недопонимаю

Comment: не стоит в одном вопросе задавать несколько вопросов. лучше задать их отдельно. Плюс обсуждение - это не формат SO.

Comment: Если честно, я очень плохо понял Вашу структуру. Модуль - это модуль. Например, модуль "записная книжка". Записная книжка может состоять из различных компонентов. Например может быть компонент "календаря", который выводит, собственно, календарь. В этом же модуле может быть другой компонент - "вывод окна для добавления комментария". Они потому и называются компонентами, что могут быть использованы в записной книжке или в каком-нибудь другом модуле посложнее, где тоже нужны календари и добавление комментариев.

Comment: У меня пока первый проект на Angular2, и я пока не знаю окончательно, какая структура будет работать. Возникла задача использовать Material Design. Нашел как минимум три разных реализации, остановился на angular-material. Требуется импортировать MaterialModule. Казалось бы, можно импортировать его на самом высоком уровне и использовать на всех более низких. Однако, почему-то не получается. Приходится создавать модуль для каждого уровня с единственной целью - импортировать MaterialModule. Чувствую, что что-то здесь не правильно. Продолжу эксперименты.

Comment: Отключил модули трех подуровней. Вроде, работает. Значит, они и не нужны. Продолжу эксперименты, но буду рад любым советам.

Answer (score 0):

1. Затем, что это совершенно разные сущности. Именно для того чтобы не надо было в разных компонентах одного модуля сто раз повторять одинаковые imports, providers и declarations.
2. Не понял сути вопроса.
3. При желании в одном файле можно вообще весь код приложения держать, и шаблоны, и стили, вопрос зачем.

На вопрос "как лучше" однозначного ответа вы не найдете, сколько людей - столько мнений. Есть [стайл гайд](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html), который опять таки носит рекомендательный характер.

Comment: 1. Вот именно это "разные компоненты одного модуля" и интересует.