# Последовательность загрузки модулей и компонентов в Angular2

Tags: angular2

Продолжение [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599057/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B2-angular2)

Структура такая:

Модуль0

--Компонент0

----Компонент1

------Компонент2, Модуль2

--------Компонент3

В Модуль0 задекларированы Компонент0, Компонент1, Компонент2 и импортирован Модуль2
В Модуль2 задекларирован Компонент3.

Компонент0 содержит тег Компонента1, Компонент1-тег Компонента2, Компонент2-тег Компонента3.

В итоге Angular "не видит" Компонент3, хотя он задекларирован в Модуле2, который, в свою очередь, импортируется в Модуле0.

Если Компонент3 задекларировать в Модуле0, то все в порядке, то тогда Модуль2 Вообще не нужен.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы Компонент3 декларировался Только на уровне Компонента2 и не выше? Хочу сделать Компонент2 "закрытым" элементом, чтобы с уровня Компонента1 и выше был виден только тег Компонента2, а содержимое его было скрыто.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел!

В Module2, помимо

declarations: [Component2]

следует добавить также

exports: [Component2]. И все работает